# search for wallet address holding native tokens

Tags: native

One particular use case is as follows:

- native token is issued and we would like to know the wallet addresses holding this native tokens.
- And then use loyalty point based calculation to give rewards to the token holders as these tokens are both acting as governance and as value holding mechanism.

So the question is how would for a particular native token, minted on cardano create such a system. ALGO for example does this for their token. How can i query for a particular native token and get this information at any point in time ?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend db-sync, graphql or cardano-rosetta for this. The wallet is designed for tracking all addresses associated with one root key. From the perspective of someone wanting to give loyalty tokens to holders, all you care about is what addresses hold utxos containing your token. This has no bearing on if a holder has one address or multiple in a wallet holding the same native token.

Answer (score 0):

If running db-sync is not a solution for you, try [/api/v0/assets/{asset}/addresses](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Assets/paths/%7E1assets%7E1%7Basset%7D%7E1addresses/get) endpoint at Blockfrost.io.